# point inside a triangle

Tags: 3d, geometry, system, point

I wanted to ask you if anyone knew how to check if a point was inside a given triangle, on a reference system in space.
I am aware that speaking of 2d systems I can obtain this point with the following procedures:
To determine if a given point v lies within a given triangle, consider a single vertex, denoted v0, v1 and v2 are the vectors from the other two vertices v0. Expressing the vector from v0 to v in terms of v1 and v2 then gives

*v = v0 + av1 + bv2*

where a, b are constant. Solve for a, b

*a= (det (v v2) - det (v0 v2)) / (det (v1 v2))

b=  - (det (v v1) - det (v0 v1)) / (det (v1 v2))*

So the point v is inside the triangle if a, b> 0 e a + b <1.
I was wondering if there was a similar procedure or not.

After MBo's advice I wrote the following code:

```
    def pointLocatedOnTheTriangularFace(self, point):
    vertList = list(self.vertices)
    system = []
    for i in range(4):
        p = vertList[1].coords-vertList[0].coords
        q = vertList[2].coords-vertList[0].coords
        n = np.cross(p,q)
        for i in range(3):
            system.append([p[i],q[i],n[i]])
        try:
            solution = list(np.linalg.solve(system,np.array(point-vertList[0].coords)))
            if solution[0] > 0 and solution[1] > 0 and solution[0]+solution[1]<1 and solution[2]==0:
                return True
        except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
            print("The system having the floor {0} {1} {2} with the point {3} does not admit solutions.\n".format(vertList[0].coords,vertList[1].coords,vertList[2].coords,point))
        v = vertList.pop(0)
        vertList.append(v)
    return False
```

I am working with tetrahedra, and the triangles that interest me are the faces of the tetrahedron. I state that it does not work but I can not understand why. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?
I changed the code in the following way and it seems to work.

```
def pointLocatedOnTheTriangularFace(self, point):
    vertList = list(self.vertices)
    system = []
    for i in range(4):
        r = point-vertList[0].coords
        p = vertList[1].coords-vertList[0].coords
        q = vertList[2].coords-vertList[0].coords
        n = np.cross(p,q)
        if np.inner(r,n) == 0:
            system = [[p[0],q[0]],[p[1],q[1]]]
            try:
                solution = list(np.linalg.solve(system,np.array([r[0],r[1]])))
                if solution[0] > 0 and solution[1] > 0 and solution[0]+solution[1]<1:
                    return True
            except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
                print("The system having the floor {0} {1} {2} with the point {3} does not admit solutions.\n".format(vertList[0].coords,vertList[1].coords,vertList[2].coords,point))
        v = vertList.pop(0)
        vertList.append(v)
    return False
```

With the following tests:

```
def test_PointPlacedOnTheTriangularFace(self):
    tr1Vertices = [vertex([0,4.32978e-17,0.5],1),vertex([-0.433013,0.25,-0.5],2),vertex([-4.32978e-17,-0.5,-0.5],3),vertex([0.433013,0.25,-0.5],4)]
    tr1= tetrahedron(tr1Vertices)
    point = vertex([0,0,-0.5],1)
    self.assertTrue(tr1.pointLocatedOnTheTriangularFace(point.coords), msg="In this test the point is inside the face")

def test_PointNotPlacedLocatedOnTheTriangularFace(self):
    tr1Vertices = [vertex([0,4.32978e-17,0.5],1),vertex([-0.433013,0.25,-0.5],2),vertex([-4.32978e-17,-0.5,-0.5],3),vertex([0.433013,0.25,-0.5],4)]
    tr1= tetrahedron(tr1Vertices)
    point = vertex([1,0,-0.5],1)
    self.assertFalse(tr1.pointLocatedOnTheTriangularFace(point.coords), msg="In this test the point is outside the face")
```

If anyone has any advice for me I will surely treasure it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Described 2D approach is essentially decomposition of vector `r = v-v0` by basis vectors `p=v1-v0` and `q=v2-v0`.

In 3D you can decompose vector `r` by vectors `p`, `q` and `n = p x q` (where `x` denotes vector product operation)

If resulting coefficients `a,b,c` fulfill limits `a, b > 0, a + b < 1, c=0`, then point `v` lies in triangle plane inside it.

For decomposition solve this linear system for unknowns `a,b,c`:

```
rx = a * px + b * qx + c * nx
ry = a * py + b * qy + c * ny
rz = a * pz + b * qz + c * nz
```

Alternative approach - check that dot product `r.dot.n` is zero - in this case point lies in the plane, coefficient `с` is zero, and you can solve simplified system for `a` and `b`  choosing a pair of equations and excluding the third summand (same method as in 2D)

Comment: Excuse me MBo, I understand that I have to verify that c is equal to zero, but do I have to take into account even if it was close to zero? Maybe for any floating point errors?

Comment: Do these conditions also take into account the situation where the point is on the side of the triangle?

Comment: Yes, it is worth to check values with some tolerance. Sometimes one might compare absolute `c` value with `Eps`(like `10^-6`) or `Eps*|n|`  where |n| is length of `n` vector that is equal to doubled triangle area